# Confuse about angular custom directive scope inherit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-scope

I define a custom directive in a controller, I have already define some variable in the controller's `$scope`.

```
    myapp.controller('demoController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.userInput = "Hello World";
    });

    myapp.directive('custom', function () {
        return {
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="userInput" value="{{userInput}}" />'
        }
    });
```

the html:

```
    <div controller="demoController">
    <custom></custom>
```

I thought the `custom` directive could inherit the parent contoller's `$scope`, so it could access to the `userInput` variable. But when page render out, nothing happened. the input element show nothing.

Should not the custom directive inherit the parent's scope? How can make it right?

Comment: you don't need to specify `value=` because `ng-model` handles that for you;  I think if you remove that, the directive should work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your div to use `ng-controller`

```
  <div ng-controller="demoController">
```